# How to connect to oracle from a sharepoint solution?

Tags: c#, oracle, sharepoint

I want to create a wsp which connects sharepoint to oracle. On my research on this i came to know that i can use either Oracle.DataAccess dll or System.Data.OracleClient. But both of them are not sucessfull. Oracle.DataAccess dll can only be used with its dependencies. It throws error as" Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format." Also it cannot be added along with a wsp where as System.Data.OracleClient throws error "Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed." 
Please help!!!!! Please give me a solution for this problem!!!1

Answer (score 0):

'Could not load file or assembly' probably throws because you're using the 32bit Oracle.DataAccess dll, and SharePoint (assuming 2010 or 2013) only runs in 64 bit mode. Install the right 64bit assembly (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) and try again.